# Changing the rootViewController of a UIWindow

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uiwindow, rootview

When my app first loads, I set the `rootViewController` property of my `UIWindow` to `controllerA`.

Sometime during my app, I choose to change the `rootViewController` to `controllerB`.

The issue is that sometimes when I do a flip transition in `controllerB`, I see `controllerA`'s view behind it. For some reason that view isn't getting removed. Whats even more worrying is that after setting the `rootViewController` to `controllerB`, `controllerA`'s `dealloc` method never gets fired.

I've tried removing the subviews of `UIWindow` manually before switching to `controllerB`, that solves the issue of seeing `controllerA`'s views in the background but `controllerA`'s dealloc still never gets called. **Whats going on here????**

Apples docs say:

> The root view controller provides the content view of the window. Assigning a view controller to this property (either programmatically or using Interface Builder) installs the view controller’s view as the content view of the window. If the window has an existing view hierarchy, the old views are removed before the new ones are installed.

**UPDATE**

Here's the code of my AppDelegate:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    [self showControllerA];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}

- (void)showControllerA
{
    ControllerA* a = [ControllerA new];
    self.window.rootViewController = a;
}

- (void) showControllerB {
    ControllerB* b = [ControllerB new];
    self.window.rootViewController = b;
}
```

Comment: Can you provide the code for your `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` method in your app delegate?

Comment: Stupid question, but do you set the `controllerA` to nil when you push the second controller?  If not then it will not dealloc.  (I'm assuming you are)

Comment: I never keep a pointer to controllerA so not sure what I would set to nil.

Comment: @Cezar just updated the question with a condensed version of my app delegate code

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It turns out there are two separate issues. 1) I had a retain cycle in Controller A so it was never getting dealloc'd. Secondly, in order to change the root view controller you must remove the windows subviews first (even though the docs suggest otherwise)

Answer (score 1):

The problem could be in your implementation of ControllerA or ControllerB, they may retain 'self' in the code so ARC cant automatically dealloc you ViewController. Can you post you ControllerA and ControllerB implementation.

Comment: That would explain why dealloc isn't getting called. But why would the view from controllerA still be visible behind controllerB. Doesn't changing the root view controller remove controllerA's views from the window?

Answer (score 0):

```
var loginNavigationController: OnBoardViewController?{
    willSet{
        if newValue == nil {
            loginNavigationController?.view.removeFromSuperview()
        }
    }
}
```

loginNavigationController = nil

Answer (score 0):

It's apple's bug, we assume ViewControllerA as the current rootViewController:

```
// ViewControllerA.m
- (void)buttonClick {
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{
        // [((AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]) resetRoot]; // OK
    }];

    [((AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]) resetRoot]; // ViewControllerA's view will not dealloc 
}

// AppDelegate.m
- (void)resetRoot {
    ViewControllerB *controller = [[ViewControllerB alloc] init];
    self.window.rootViewController = controller;
}
```

If reset window's rootViewController as this code, the ViewControllerA's view will never dealloc.

Answer (score 0):

An even simpler solution is to set the `backgroundColor` of your new window to `.white` or any color. The default is nil, which results in a transparent background. That is why the older window (on top of which the new one is made visible) is being seen through.